# How to typecast long to ByteValue() in schema of pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, json, database, apache-spark, pyspark

This is my schema from `df.printSchema()`:

```
root
 |-- C_0_0: double (nullable = true)
 |-- C_0_1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- C_2_0: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: decimal(10,6) (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- C_2_1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- C_0_2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- C_2_0: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- C_3_0: decimal(10,6) (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- C_3_1: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- C_2_1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- C_3_0: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- C_3_1: double (nullable = true)
```

Upon printing the schema i.e. `df.schema` I get:

```
Schema:  StructType([StructField('C_0_0', DoubleType(), True), StructField('C_0_1', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('C_2_0', ArrayType(DecimalType(10,6), True), True), StructField('C_2_1', ArrayType(**LongType()**, True), True)]), True), True), StructField('C_0_2', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('C_2_0', StructType([StructField('C_3_0', DecimalType(10,6), True), StructField('C_3_1', DoubleType(), True)]), True), StructField('C_2_1', StructType([StructField('C_3_0', TimestampType(), True), StructField('C_3_1', DoubleType(), True)]), True)]), True), True)])
```

I want the LongType() to be ByteType() ?

These are my desired datatypes in df:
Basic Datatypes:  ['DOUBLE', 'DECIMAL(10,6)', 'SMALLINT', 'DECIMAL(10,6)', 'DOUBLE', 'TIMESTAMP', 'DOUBLE']

pyspark df does not understand smallint.
This is the JSON for the schema:

```
## Schema in dict:  

{'fields': [{'metadata': {}, 'name': 'C_0_0', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'double'}, {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'C_0_1', 'nullable': True, 'type': {'containsNull': True, 'elementType': {'fields': [{'metadata': {}, 'name': 'C_2_0', 'nullable': True, 'type': {'containsNull': True, 'elementType': 'double', 'type': 'array'}}, {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'C_2_1', 'nullable': True, 'type': {'containsNull': True, 'elementType': **'long'**, 'type': 'array'}}], 'type': 'struct'}, 'type': 'array'}}, {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'C_0_2', 'nullable': True, 'type': {'containsNull': True, 'elementType': {'fields': [{'metadata': {}, 'name': 'C_2_0', 'nullable': True, 'type': {'fields': [{'metadata': {}, 'name': 'C_3_0', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'double'}, {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'C_3_1', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'double'}], 'type': 'struct'}}, {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'C_2_1', 'nullable': True, 'type': {'fields': [{'metadata': {}, 'name': 'C_3_0', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'}, {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'C_3_1', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'double'}], 'type': 'struct'}}], 'type': 'struct'}, 'type': 'array'}}], 'type': 'struct'}
```

Here I want the schema to be ByteType() when modified.

What can be done for this?
This is my current working.

```
def checkforbase(self, val):
        if isinstance(val,dict) or val=='array' or val == 'struct':
            return False
        else:
            return True
    
    def modifySchema(self, schema):
        global cnt
        
        if 'type' in schema:
            if self.checkforbase(schema['type']):
                if basic_datatypes[cnt] == "SMALLINT":
                    basic_datatypes[cnt] = "LONG"
                schema['type'] = basic_datatypes[cnt].lower()
                cnt = cnt + 1
            elif isinstance(schema['type'], dict):
                # print("Recursive again: ", d['type'])
                self.modifySchema(schema['type'])
        if 'elementType' in schema:
            if self.checkforbase(schema['elementType']):
                if basic_datatypes[cnt] == "SMALLINT":
                    basic_datatypes[cnt] = "LONG"
                schema['elementType'] = basic_datatypes[cnt].lower()
                cnt = cnt + 1
            elif isinstance(schema['elementType'], dict):
                self.modifySchema(schema['elementType'])
        if 'fields' in schema:
            full_field = schema['fields']
            for i in range(len(full_field)):
                self.modifySchema(full_field[i])
```